# Python NLTK visualization

Tags: python, nltk, nltk-trainer

I am currently doing natural language processing using python NLTK. I want to generate some beautiful graphics of the representation of input. What package can I do to get something like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the images from? They look like D3 outputs =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) is the go-to visualization library for Python. Have a look at its [gallery](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html) to see what it can do. I actually don't know if it can generate the kind of images you've shown though.

[Altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair) is another capable plotting library which kindly includes a few links to other libraries in its README:

- [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)
- [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)
- [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/#)
- [Lightning](http://lightning-viz.org/)
- [Plotly](https://plot.ly/)
- [Pandas built-in plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)
- [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/)
- [VisPy](http://vispy.org/)
- [pygg](http://www.github.com/sirrice/pygg)